# How can I easily flatten the tupled elements that come out of SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm writing code similar to the example below, but it feels clunky. Is there a better way to get a flat list out of a SQLAlchemy query? If I don't do the list comprehension, the list is a list of tuples.

```
names = [x[0] for x in session.query(User.name).all()]
```

I'd like some magical function like `Query.scalar` but for a list.

Comment: You could define a function and use that... List comprehensions are great for this sort of thing

Comment: It's not an answer to your question, but you can write `x.name` instead of `x[0]`.

Comment: Yup! Thanks. I voted to close it.